# Stack Exchange chat blocked under "Gaming" classification

Tags: support, chat

*Note: I'm not sure if there's anything much that can be done, but I vaguely recall @Jeff mentioning about bringing up incorrect website classification(I can't find his quote now) on Meta, so I'm posting this anyway.*

The root domain for [Stack Exchange chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) seems to have triggered the web filter and now visiting that site results in this.... page.

[image]

I believe the Web Filter at work is [Web(non)sense](http://www.websense.com), and was wondering if there's anything that can be done by SOIS to get this classification changed.

(Also, for the time being - direct URLs to the specified chat rooms do open - though I'm not sure for how long :( )

Comment: You need a larger monitor, so you need to talk to your boss anyhow! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a direct link to [your profile page.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/65/sathya) If it works you can use it to get into your commonly joined rooms.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it at work tomorrow @radp

Answer (score 4):

I worry if we follow up, this will be (correctly) classified as "chat" and likely blocked for similar reason.

Pick your poison..

Comment: Which is the case currently at work for me. Because the word chat appears in the Url, it's blocked.

Comment: But as you said it *is* chat, and should be classified as such. Besides, as chat can sometimes be used for professional reasons but gaming cannot, I assume that the chat classification is better anyway.

Comment: @oak see [How do I prevent a website being misclassified by Websense?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/website-misclassified-by-websense)  for more detail

Comment: You have a point here @Jeff chat or gaming - both will be blocked (soon). In the end, I guess correct classification would be better.

Comment: The domain wasn't blocked yesterday, and hopefully will continue to be so. @JeffAtwood

Answer (score 1):

The rooms for Gaming.SE are pretty popular, so I would say that the classification is correct. A significant part of Chat.SE is related to gaming.

The only way to generally prevent such classification that I can think of would be to move Gaming.Chat and similar sites to a different domain. I don't know if that would be worth the effort.

Comment: It's related to talking **about** gaming, not to play games @Fabian

Comment: @Ivo I don't know if that category is meant to block only online games, or also forums about games and similar sites. And any automated filter is probably not capable of making that distinction.

Comment: Which is why automated filters are probably not a good idea in an IT company...

Comment: Or any kind of filter for that matter...

Comment: @Ivo What about the easter egg? Wouldn't that kinda classify it as a game? ♪

Comment: I have no idea how the filter would recognize the Easter Egg either

Comment: @Ivo I'm pretty sure it's not a mistake for a corporate filter to block access to forums that talk about games; they would describe that as a feature

Comment: My organization blocks Gaming, but not Gaming Meta, Chat, or Board & Card Games...