# Meta.Programmers is blocked by WebSense for "Uncategorized"

Tags: support, per-site-meta, blocked

It actually appears that Meta.*.stackexchange.com is, but Meta.StackOverflow is not.

In a previous discussion about [the blocking of Chat by WebSense](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74636/stack-exchange-chat-blocked-under-gaming-classification), it looks like there's not much Stack Exchange could do about that one. But filtering Meta sites seems like it might be handled by trying to make sure Meta is classified the same as the primary site...

Comment: Oh, the joys of censorware...

Comment: @YannisRizos I know. I'm totally talking to HR after I get back from my trip this week. We have this "People Policy" and one of the bullets is "mutual trust and respect". This is totally not trusting and respecting me. Plus, it now makes it nearly impossible for me to do mod things on Programmers during those weekly 2 hour "omg test ALL THE THINGS" tests and lunch time.

Comment: Are you certain it's your company's fault and not a WebSense snafu? Like when they blocked [cisco.com](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/03/20/websense_blocks_cisco/) and [bing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/06/02/websense_lifts_bing_block/)...

Comment: @YannisRizos I want WebSense to go away at work. Why do you need to filter the Internet of people you trust and respect to do the right thing and not be total idiots?

Comment: Oh, good luck with that. Be prepared for to counter a ton of stock arguments...

Comment: "the Internet of people you trust and respect" - That's your first problem right there. =)

Comment: @casperOne I was referring to the people who are using the Internet from the office and behind WebSense, not the other people on the Internet. I don't trust the Internet. It's full of wrong people that I need to correct. I do it a lot.